# How to remove from am array in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import dateDiff from 'date-diff';
import moment from 'moment';


const calcDate = (date) => {
    let newDate = moment(new Date(date)).fromNow();
    console.log(newDate)
   return newDate;
};//end of calcDate

const removeByIndex = (state=[], index) => {
};



const addToListReducer = (state=[], action) => {
    let reminders;

    
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_LIST':
            reminders = [...state, {task: action.task, dueDate:calcDate(action.dueDate)}]
            console.log('this is the reminders in the reducer', reminders);
            return reminders;
        case "REMOVE_FROM_LIST":
            console.log("Removing from the list", action.index)
            reminders = removeByIndex(state, action.index)
            return reminders;
        default:
            return state;

    } //end of switch statement
}

export default addToListReducer;
```

On the removeByIndex function, I am passing the state(the full array of task) and the index number of that array. How would i delete the element of that array by using the index. I feel since it is react, that i need to use a filter in it?

Comment: `arr.filter((elem, index) => return index !== action.index);`

Comment: `arr.slice(0, action.index).concat(arr.slice(action.index+1))` would also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, since you are using Redux, the state needs to be immutable. So you can't edit the array directly and return the same instance of it, but instead you've to create a new one.

In the [redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays), it explains few ways of how to do it.

So you could do:

```
function removeItem(array, index) {
    return [
        ...array.slice(0, index), // first part of the array, 0 to index (excluded)
        ...array.slice(index + 1) // the rest, after the index
    ];
}
```

Or simply (but may be less performant):

```
function removeItem(array, index) {
    return array.filter((_, i) => i !== index); // all items except at index
}
```

Comment: In this case, I would not recommend using "filter" to remove by index. Concatenating the slices should be readable enough and is significantly more efficient.

Comment: `filter` may be more readable and shorter (especially if `removeItem` is converted to a lambda), but you're right that if performance is a concern then the first should be used. I've updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I guess readability is in the eyes of the beholder ;) You've earned my +1